# React undefined map output

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In react I would like to return and display a listing but in the following code, my `listing` is undefined in the log, why ? I have no error message

```
burgerListing = () => {

 const list = this.state.burgerList       

 const listing = list.map( burger => {
                     <div key={burger.id}>
                         <h3>{burger.name}</h3>
                         <strong>{burger.price}</strong>
                         <p>{burger.description}</p>
                     </div>
                 })

 console.log(listing);

 return listing

}; 


render(){

    return(
        <div>
            <this.burgerListing  />
       </div>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not returning anything from your `.map()`, you need to do:

```
const listing = list.map( burger => {
  return (
    <div key={burger.id}>
     <h3>{burger.name}</h3>
     <strong>{burger.price}</strong>
     <p>{burger.description}</p>
    </div>
   )   
})
```

Comment: that was it; I thought it was enough to return listing at the end.. thank you !

Comment: Cool, if it helped please mark as correct :)

Comment: @Colin..Do we need to call parenthesis () in render to call this arrow function..??